# JS error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, payment-gateway

I am getting this error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined` in a credit card terminal form.

The offending line is: `$('#exp-month').val(arr[2].substring(2, 4));`

This is the whole function.

```
function checkForReaderInput(string) {
if (string.substring(0,2) == "%B") {
string = string.replace('%B', '');
var arr = string.split('^');
if (arr[0].length == 16) {
$('#cardnumber').val(arr[0]);
$('#exp-month').val(arr[2].substring(2, 4));
$('#exp-year').val('20'+arr[2].substring(0, 2));
var nameArr = arr[1].split('/');
$('#cardholdername').val(nameArr[1]+' '+nameArr[0]);
setMOP(arr[0].substring(0,1));
}
cardParsed = true;
$('#sdkinputid_cardnumber span.errortext').hide();
return false;
}
setMOP(string.substring(0,1));  // for manual CC# entry
}
```

What this should do is take the reader input from the `cardnumber` field and seperate it to fill the form. It does get the card number field but the cursor stays there and the form tries to submit. Alone this works. This did not start happening until I tried including it in a bootstrap form. I got rid of all the validation. All thats left is the stripe gateway scripts.

The page is no longer available

Comment: arr[2] is not returning anything. You are trying to perform a substring method on something that's undefined. I would try console.log($('#exp-month').val()); to see what you're returning.

Comment: on the page I see the script `$("#cardnumber").change(function () { checkForReaderInput($(this).val()); } )` but I don't the element with id `cardnumber` anywhere. Can you just put in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when I moved to the new form I forgot an ID that surrounds the form. Once I replace it the errors went away and it auto completes.